# Rename an attribute of html file in c#

Tags: c#, .net, html-parsing

I have a `HTML` inside a string variable, which contains some `<img>` tags. I want to replace the `src` attribute with `data-realsrc` attribute and put `loading.gif` in `src` attribute.

For example, if this is one of `<img>` tags:

```
<img src="Hello.jpg" />
```

I want to change it to:

```
<img data-realsrc="Hello.jpg" src="loading.gif" />
```

It should be applied to all `<img>` tags inside the `HTML`.

Please note that **I want to do it server-side with c#**.

How to do that?

What is the simplest way? What is the fastest way?

Comment: Have you tried the *String.Replace*?

Comment: @AVD There should be many `src=`s in the page. (example: `<script src=...`) also it may be `src =` and...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(@"<img src=""Hello.jpg"" />");

foreach (var img in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img"))
{
    var realSource = img.Attributes["data-realsrc"];

    if (realSource != null)
        realSource.Value = img.Attributes["src"].Value;
    else
        img.Attributes.Add("data-realsrc", img.Attributes["src"].Value);

    img.Attributes["src"].Value = "loading.gif";
}
```